# How to increase the performance of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, database-performance

I have a query to be executed in PostgreSQL, which  gives nearly 1,00,0000 records and is taking too much time to execute.

The server is installed in Ubuntu having 16 GB RAM. We have indexed the query to increase the performance and still taking time.
Also I tried by changing some parameters like work_mem and effective_cache_size but there is no reasonable changes.

Can anyone suggest a suitable values that  can be given for the performance related parameters in PostgreSQL for 16 GB RAM Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete query you are running  and [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` and `create table` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: My query connects 9 tables and we have applied indexing also. I will attach the query plan generated using explain analyze.  Whether I can do some changes in performance parameters so that it run faster?

Comment: We won't know what we can learn from the plan has to say until after you show it to us.